# Sum and group multiple fields by date + other field

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table with 3 columns as shown below.  I would like to summarize the cost for each TYPE (only 0/1/2), and then group it by Month and Year (of the DATE field), all using a select statement.

```
+------------+------+-------+
| DATE       | TYPE | COST  |
+------------+------+-------+
| Feb-1-2003 |  0   | 19.40 |
| Feb-5-2010 |  1   | 28.10 |
| Mar-3-2011 |  2   | 64.20 |
| Sep-8-2012 |  0   | 22.60 |
| Dec-6-2013 |  1   | 13.50 |
+------------+------+-------+
```

The output would look like:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| PERIOD   | TYPE0      | TYPE1      | TYPE2      |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| Jan 2003 | 123123.12  | 23432.12   | 9873245.12 |
| Feb 2003 | 123123.12  | 23432.12   | 9873245.12 |
| Mar 2003 | 123123.12  | 23432.12   | 9873245.12 |
etc...
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Can someone help with this select statement?

Comment: never mine, an answer already posted, and its a great answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql is not designed for pivot queries.  It's better to aggregate in some other language..  That's not to say it's impossible, though:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(MONTH(DATE), ' ', YEAR(DATE)) AS PERIOD,
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 0, COST, 0)) AS TYPE0,
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 1, COST, 0)) AS TYPE1,
    SUM(IF(TYPE = 2, COST, 0)) AS TYPE2
FROM
    t1
GROUP BY
    PERIOD
```

Comment: Wow - very nice and simple!  Thanks

Comment: One related problem, the output is sorted by period BUT in order lime Month =10,11,12,1,2,3 etc.  due to space.  Is there a way to format month as double digit (or fix the sort) in PERIOD?

Comment: @Michelle you can; `WHERE` clause must go before `GROUP BY` but after `FROM`