# What is the best way of retrieving data from same table but different time frames?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm just a little unsure as to how I approach this. This is the information I have to output:

[image: output]

What would be the best way to do it? I have a table called "payments" and a table called "referral_earnings" (example).

payments:
`user_id | type (file or link) | amount | created_at (DATETIME)`

referral_earnings:
`user_id (user receiving the payment) | amount | created_at`

I'll be caching the results of the query for X minutes. I'm just not sure the best way to create a query to do this? The part I'm struggling with is the different time frames.

Thanks!

EDIT: Okay the problem I'm having now is differentiating between files, links and referrals in the same query

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362989/1073419

Comment: I wouldn't do this in one query, but many queries: one for each timeframe. Does that help you come up with a solution?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yeah, I could certainly do that, but it just feels a little "wasteful". If I did do it this way, best to run a query for each timeframe and SUM the amount col?

Comment: As @FritsvanCampen said, I believe this is way the best way to do it.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen What would be the best way to incorporate the other table (referrals) and differentiation between the type column in one query for the time frame?

Comment: Do 3 queries for each time frame I guess, one for each type. Just keep it simple. Unless there is a performance problem, this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). They come in very handy

```
class Stats extends Eloquent{

      public function scopefileStats($query, $timeFrame){
            $query->where('user_id', = ,Auth::user()->id);
            $query->where('created_at','>', DB::raw($timeFrame));
            $query->where('type','=','FILE');
      }

      public function scopelinkStats($query,$timeFrame){
            $query->where('user_id', = ,Auth::user()->id);
            $query->where('created_at','>', DB::raw($timeFrame));
            $query->where('type','=','LINK');
      }

      public function scopereferralStats($query,$timeFrame){
            $query->where('user_id', = ,Auth::user()->id);
            $query->where('created_at','>', DB::raw($timeFrame));
            $query->where('type','=','REFERRAL');
      }
}
```

Retrieve data as

```
Stats::fileStats('date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')->sum('amount');
Stats::linkStats('date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')->sum('amount');
Stats::referralStats('date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')->sum('amount');
```

This is probably one of the ways you can do this, but you can always customize the above code as per your comfort factor.

Answer (score 0):

probably you may make use of Mysql date/time function,

```
created_at > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) // for last month
created_at> date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) // for last week
created_at> date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) // for yesterday
```

Comment: Yep- but how do I differentiate for files, links and referrals in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Write a query (stored proc - assuming you are pairing with mysql) and call that query (stored proc) each time you need to grab data from those tables.  Pass in your datetime as a parameter to the stored proc.  Depending on your needs, you could even just use the built-in "getDateTime" function in whatever db you are using to avoid having to pass in the datetime.

I just reread the original post - you would actually pass in parameters for your other variables as well (userid).

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
DB::select("
    SELECT
        SUM(IF(TYPE = 'file', conversions.user_payout, 0)) AS files,
        SUM(IF(TYPE = 'link', conversions.user_payout, 0)) AS links,
        (SELECT 
            SUM(amount) FROM referral_earnings WHERE user_id = :user_id1 AND date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
        ) AS referrals 
    FROM 
        conversions
    WHERE 
        conversions.user_id = :user_id2 
        AND date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
", [
    'user_id1' => 3, 
    'user_id2' => 3
]);
```

Thanks to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362519/1073419
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906832/1073419

Appreciate all the help!